# Need help aggregating mongoose data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mern

I have a MERN stack application and when I make a GET call I want to return the votes of all of my MongoDB objects.

This is what my objects look like:

```
{_id: ObjectId("6092d48d96984d233cf77152")
user: "John Doe"
movies: [
     0:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Alpha",
          ranking: 3
     1:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Bravo",
          ranking: 2
     2:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Charlie",
          ranking: 1
]}

{_id: ObjectId("6092d48d96984d233cf77152")
user: "John Doe"
movies: [
     0:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Alpha",
          ranking: 3
     1:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Bravo",
          ranking: 2
     2:
          _id: ObjectId("6092b19345f48a33447468a7"),
          title: "Charlie",
          ranking: 1
]}
```

Obviously there will be more data but basically I would like it to return:

```
[{title: "Alpha", ranking: 6},
{title: "Bravo", ranking: 4},
{title: "Charlie", ranking: 2}]
```

I assume I have to use the `$match` function but this is my first time using Mongoose/MongoDB like this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `movies` array
- `$group` by `movies.title` and sum `ranking`

```
let result = await YourModelName.aggregate([ // replace your model name
  { $unwind: "$movies" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$movies.title",
      ranking: { $sum: "$movies.ranking" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1kVsx7I5X_s)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I knew something was weird with the movies array